# Cocos2d 2.0 and OpenGL analyizer suggestions

Tags: xcode, performance, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

I have analyzed my game running OpenGL Analyzer on XCode. I am using Cococs2d 2.0 as static library in my game and wonder **whether any of the following suggestions will improve my performance**. I have read some post in other forums saying that I should not worry about this but as I do have some performance issues I would like to understand if those suggestion will be likely to improve them.

**Suggestions:**

[image: Detailed view]

**Overview:**

[image: Overview]

**Thinking:**

In particular I refer to the suggestion where it says:
"*reccomended using VAO and VBO*"

Then I wonder also why there are "*Many small batch draw calls*". I am using a spritebatch node and this should avoid this issue.

Also the other suggestions seems to make sense, but those are the most "frequent" ones so would like to start analyzing those.

Answer (score 0):

A "small batch draw call" is anything with fewer than n-many vertices. I am not sure the exact threshold used, but it is probably on the order of 100-200. What spritebatches really do is eliminate the need to split your draw calls up multiple times in order to switch bound textures, this does not automatically imply that each draw call is going to have more than 100 (or whatever n is defined as in this context) vertices; it is a strong possibility, but not necessary.

I would be far more concerned about non-VBO draw calls and not using VAOs to be honest, especially if you want your code to be forward-compatible.

The "Logical Buffer Load" and "Mipmapping Usage" warnings are very likely related; probably both having to do with FBOs. One of them is related to not using `glClear (...)` properly and the other is related to using a texture that does not have mipmaps.

Regarding logical buffer loads, you should look into `GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer`, clearing the framebuffer this way is a really healthy optimization strategy for Tile-Based Deferred Rendering GPUs (such as the ones used by all iOS devices).

As for the mipmap usage warning, I believe this is being triggered because you are drawing into an FBO texture and then applying that texture using a mipmap filter mode. The mip-chain/pyramid for drawn FBOs has to be built manually using `glGenerateMipamp (...)`.

If you can point me to some individual lines that trigger these warnings, I would be happy to explain them in further detail for you.